# How do I check the postfix queue size?

Tags: postfix

What's the postfix equivalent to `sendmail -bp`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Or, less typing:

```
mailq
```

Answer (score 32):

```
postqueue -p
```

Answer (score 30):

```
qshape active
```

will show you the number of emails being sent to each domain and how long they have been in the active queue

```
qshape deferred
```

will show you the same but for the deferred queue

Answer (score 21):

Here's what I use, culled from the postfix mailing list.  I removed the author's name, in case he doesn't want it here (you can see it at the source).  It only displays totals.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# postfix queue/s size
# author: 
# source: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/postfix-users/message/255133

use strict;
use warnings;
use Symbol;
sub count {
        my ($dir) = @_;
        my $dh = gensym();
        my $c = 0;
        opendir($dh, $dir) or die "$0: opendir: $dir: $!\n";
        while (my $f = readdir($dh)) {
                if ($f =~ m{^[A-F0-9]{5,}$}) {
                        ++$c;
                } elsif ($f =~ m{^[A-F0-9]$}) {
                        $c += count("$dir/$f");
                }
        }
        closedir($dh) or die "closedir: $dir: $!\n";
        return $c;
}
my $qdir = `postconf -h queue_directory`;
chomp($qdir);
chdir($qdir) or die "$0: chdir: $qdir: $!\n";
printf "Incoming: %d\n", count("incoming");
printf "Active: %d\n", count("active");
printf "Deferred: %d\n", count("deferred");
printf "Bounced: %d\n", count("bounce");
printf "Hold: %d\n", count("hold");
printf "Corrupt: %d\n", count("corrupt");
```

EDIT: Fixed a typo on line 26.

Comment: Great script, and IMHO should be a part of the standard Postfix distribution.  Unlike mailq/postqueue returns immediate answer for a queue under duress

Comment: Just a word of caution on the particular implementation of `count` function.  It will fail in Postfix 2.9+ when enable_long_queue_ids=yes'.  I think it should not be too hard to fix it for long queue ids.

Comment: Fixed version posted below, https://serverfault.com/a/1119113/52485.

Answer (score 15):

`postqueue -p | tail -n 1`

Last line in the `postqueue -p` shows how many requests and size:

`-- 317788 Kbytes in 11860 Requests.`

Comment: This command executes quickly since it doesn't waste cycles displaying the individual emails in the queue. If just want the total, run this.

Answer (score 6):

[root@server ~]# time mailq | grep -c '^[0-9A-Z]'

10

real    0m1.333s

user    0m0.003s

sys     0m0.003s

(above result indicating that there are 10 email is queue)

Comment: More concisely: mailq | grep -c '^\w'

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have `qshape` you can install it via the following yum commands:

`yum groupinstall perl development`
`yum install postfix-perl-scripts`

qshape prints Postfix queue domain and age distribution information. You can read more about it here:

http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html

#### Example output

```
% qshape -s hold | head
                         T  5 10 20 40 80 160 320 640 1280 1280+
                 TOTAL 486  0  0  1  0  0   2   4  20   40   419
             yahoo.com  14  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   1    0    12
  extremepricecuts.net  13  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   2    0    11
        ms35.hinet.net  12  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    1    11
      winnersdaily.net  12  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   2    0    10
           hotmail.com  11  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    1    10
           worldnet.fr   6  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     6
        ms41.hinet.net   6  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0    0     6
                osn.de   5  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0    0     4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

for q in active  bounce  corrupt  defer  deferred  flush  hold  incoming  maildrop  pid  private  public  saved  trace

    do
        count=$(find /var/spool/postfix/$q ! -type d -print | wc -l)
        echo $q $count
    done
```

Answer (score 2):

I have `jq` on my system.
I like the following approach a lot:

```
postqueue -j | jq -s 'group_by(.queue_name) | map({"queue": .[0].queue_name, "count": length})'
[
  {
    "queue": "active",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "queue": "deferred",
    "count": 314
  },
  {
    "queue": "hold",
    "count": 2630
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @mikewater's answer here, since it didn't fit in a comment: this should handle old and new postfix and also shows the total.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# pfq - quickly print postfix queue sizes.
# Unlike mailq/postqueue returns immediate answer for a queue under duress.
#
# http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/postfix-users/message/255133,
# https://serverfault.com/a/329884/52485,
# SM

use strict;
use warnings;
use Symbol;
sub count {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    my $dh = gensym();
    my $c = 0;
    opendir($dh, $dir) or die "$0: opendir: $dir: $!\n";
    while (my $f = readdir($dh)) {
        if ($f =~ m{^([A-F0-9]|[0-9B-Zb-z]){5,}$}) {
            ++$c;
        } elsif ($f =~ m{^[A-F0-9]$}) {
            $c += count("$dir/$f");
        }
    }
    closedir($dh) or die "closedir: $dir: $!\n";
    return $c;
}
my $qdir = `postconf -h queue_directory`;
chomp($qdir);
chdir($qdir) or die "$0: chdir: $qdir: $!\n";
my $incoming = count("incoming");
my $active   = count("active");
my $deferred = count("deferred");
my $bounce   = count("bounce");
my $hold     = count("hold");
my $corrupt  = count("corrupt");
printf "Incoming: %7d\n", $incoming;
printf "Active:   %7d\n", $active;
printf "Deferred: %7d\n", $deferred;
printf "Bounced:  %7d\n", $bounce;
printf "Hold:     %7d\n", $hold;
printf "Corrupt:  %7d\n", $corrupt;
printf "-----------------\n";
printf "Total:    %7d\n", $incoming + $active + $deferred + $bounce + $hold + $corrupt;
```

And a wrapper to make testing easy:

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                       
# pfqcheck [N] - Check for no more than N queued postfix messages, default 50.                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                  
MAX="${1:-50}"                                                                                                                                                                    
NUM=$(pfq | tail -1 | awk '{print $2;}')                                                                                                                                          
MSG="$NUM queued emails, limit is $MAX"                                                                                                                                           
if [[ $(expr "$NUM" '<=' "$MAX") == 1 ]]                                                                                                                                          
then echo "ok: $MSG"; exit 0;                                                                                                                                                     
else echo "fail: $MSG"; exit 1;                                                                                                                                                   
fi
```